# $(\frac{a+b+c}{3})^{n+k} \geq \frac{a^nb^k+b^nc^k+c^na^k}{3}$

Tags: inequality

Let: $a,b,c \geq 0$ and $n,k \in \mathbb{N}^* $. Prove that:

$$(\frac{a+b+c}{3})^{n+k} \geq \frac{a^nb^k+b^nc^k+c^na^k}{3}$$

Here is what I try:

Let: $n+k=t$ we will use inductivation:

For $t=2$ we get the inequality: $$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2 \geq 0$$

But for $t=3$, we have to prove:

$$ \sum_{cyc}a^3+ 3\sum_{cyc}ab^2+6abc \geq 6 \sum_{cyc}ab^2(*)$$

which is hard for me,

But suppose if it is true, I will suppose for $t=p$ is true too.

Now move to $t=p+1$ and I got stuck here with the inequality $(*)$

Are there any hints? Thanks for all your helps!

Comment: as the other answer demonstrated, your conjecture is not true. You can get a similar implication in the other direction when $a,b,c$ form a triangle. For example, the following is true:
$$\dfrac{a^nb+b^nc+c^na}{3}\geq\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\cdot\dfrac{a^{n-1}b + b^{n-1}c + c^{n-1}a}{3},\,\,\, n\geq 2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let : $a=c=3 \\ b=0 $ and $n=1$ and $k=2$

And therfore :
$$(\frac{3+0+3}{3})^{1+2} \geq \frac{3^10^2+0^13^2+3^13^2}{3}
$$
$$
\implies 2^3 \ge 3^2 
$$

Finally :
**What you are trying to prove is fundamentally wrong**